# Getting id as Array in update_batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I am getting Id as Array when doing batch update. Not able to update data to my existing data table . Please help me**

My Error Message is shown below 
[Error Message as Image Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrJVF.png)

**Controller**

```html
public function update() 
{

$sID   = $this->input->post('test_id[]');
$sAmt  = $this->input->post('test_priceUpdt[]');
$sOfficeId = $this->input->post('fran_office_id');
$edited_test = array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($sID); $i++)
  {
   if(!empty($sID[$i])) 
   $edited_test[$i] = array(
    'test_id' => $sID[$i],
    'test_priceUpdt' => $sAmt[$i],
    'fran_office_id' => $sOfficeId
   );
}

$edited_test = json_encode($edited_test); 
$data['franchise_tst_pkg'] = (object)$postData = array (
    array(
     'test_id' => $sID,
     't_franchise_price' => $edited_test
    )
   
 ); 
 if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
 $this->franchise_price_model->batchTestupdate($postData))
 }

}
```

**View**

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="test_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_name; ?>" disabled>
    <input type="hidden" name="test_id[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_id; ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="test_price[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_price; ?>" disabled>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="test_priceUpdt[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_price; ?>" id="test_priceEdt">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Modal**

```html
public function batchTestupdate($data = []) 
{ $this->db
        ->update_batch($this->table_test, $data , 'test_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in your `update_batch(..)` function is structured wrongly.

**Change:**

```
$data['franchise_tst_pkg'] = (object)$postData = array (
                array(
                    'test_id' => $sID,
                    't_franchise_price' => $edited_test
                )
```

**To:**

```
$postData = array();
if(is_array($sID)){
    foreach($sID as $k=>$v){
        $postData[] = array(
            'test_id' => $v,
            't_franchise_price' => $edited_test
        );
    }
}
$data['franchise_tst_pkg'] = (object)$postData;
```

Comment: Sir I am getting error message like this , after changed the code as your suggest --   **A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: branch/Franchise_price.php

Line Number: 97**

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sir , I done with this code and it working -                                                                      
                                                                                           
                                if(!empty($sID)){
   foreach($sID as $k=>$v ){
       $postData[] = array(
           'test_id' => $v,
           't_franchise_price' => $edited_test
         );
   }
   $data['franchise_tst_pkg'] = (object)$postData;
  }

Comment: Thank u sir  for your kind support

Comment: Sir, 1 problem is occur. As for **batch update** we are expecting for one row one value will insert to the field but , here all values is updated to a single filed.For example, I have one row Id-17 , expecting only -- **{"test_id":"17","test_priceUpdt":"1221","fran_office_id":"12"}**  for row id 17 . But receiving like this to one column(named-**t_franchise_price**) of the row -----  (shown in next comment )

Comment: [{"test_id":"24","test_priceUpdt":"200","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"22","test_priceUpdt":"300","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"23","test_priceUpdt":"200","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"21","test_priceUpdt":"200","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"25","test_priceUpdt":"2000","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"17","test_priceUpdt":"1221","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"19","test_priceUpdt":"10","fran_office_id":"12"}]

**what should i do ?**

Comment: @ Karlo Kokkak , Sir - on this update_batch is it possible to without replacing the previous data next updated value will puts by comma separated as an array form on the SAME FILED . For example - **[{"test_id":"24","test_priceUpdt":"200","fran_office_id":"12"},{"test_id":"24","test_priceUpdt":"250","fran_office_id":"12"}]** - Like this , 1st updated value will stay and also 2nd updated value keep there with only Updating the **"test_priceUpdt":"200" to "test_priceUpdt":"250"** .

I am not sure, but is it possible ? please suggest me . Thanks.

Comment: Sir for your information.My one problem share with my previous comment box.

Comment: Sir for your information.My one problem share with my previous comment box.

Comment: What is the maximum records are you updating at once?

Comment: Sir , right now I have 10 no of rows and there I am updating 10no of rows with **{"test_id":"x","test_priceUpdt":"x","fran_office_id":"x"}**

Comment: And in future may be rows will be increased .
**Sir here I upload my Problem in Details ,please come to this link**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601471/codeigniter-update-batch-without-replacing-the-previous-data-next-updated-value

Answer (score 0):

You can change model as:

```
public function batchTestupdate($data = []) 
{ $this->db
        ->update_batch($this->table_test, explode(',', $data) , 'test_id');
}
```

Comment: Not run the code . getting error like --- **A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: models/branch/Franchise_price_model.php**

Comment: Try using var_dump($data) before the query. May be $data is coming insider array in array form